# Astor's pet horse

Tags: expressions

I use the phrase "all lit up like Astor's pet horse."

I cannot find the origin. I know it can be phrased in different ways but none that I have found seem to be correct. I understand it to be when Mrs. Astor had a particularly lavish party in her 5th Ave mansion and in the front window she placed one of her (live) horses adorned with lights.

Comment: https://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/mrs-astor%27s-horse/first-edition/ published 1935

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your question.  Are you saying you are looking for the origin of "lit up" as it relates to things that are adorned with lights?

Comment: Related: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Mrs.+Astor%27s+plush+horse

Comment: I found the full text of the book on [archive.org.](https://archive.org/stream/mrsastorshorse002434mbp/mrsastorshorse002434mbp_djvu.txt)

Comment: Who is Mrs Astor? Can you add some clarifying context/content so we know who/what you are referring to? Also, your question is a little unclear *in general*. The title does not mention the phrase 'all lit up', which seems to be an integral part of your question. Are you looking specifically for the origin of "all lit up like Astor's pet horse"?

Comment: +1 simply for the phrase itself.

Comment: If you're looking for an external origin, I don't see the phrase anywhere on the internet than here. If you're looking for the origin of where you came up with the phrase, it certainly seems derived from the book?

Answer (score 2):

I quote Stanley Walker, author of Mrs Astor's Horse:

> "It was in  the late nineteenth century that the gilded., over- 
>   stuffed magnificence of Mrs. Astor led the peasants  to say of any one
>   who was rather ostentatiously dolled  up: "She is dressed up like Mrs.
>   Astor's plush horse."

There is no mention of Mrs Astor or the horse being "lit up" in the book I am sorry to say.  You can find the complete text @ archive.org [here](https://archive.org/stream/mrsastorshorse002434mbp/mrsastorshorse002434mbp_djvu.txt)

Or if you prefer the photographed text you can view the book [here.](https://archive.org/details/mrsastorshorse002434mbp)    The paragraph I quoted above can be found on page 8.

Answer (score 1):

**plush horse**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/266053?rskey=68nXmF&result=1&isAdvanced=true#eid10236229)

> A toy horse made from plush. Also: the type of something ostentatious,
>   luxurious, etc.; frequently in dressed (up) like (Mrs) **Astor's plush
>   horse** and variants ((also: Mrs. Astor’s pet goat, cow, pet cow, plush horse)

Plush horse was in use in 1891, and Mrs Astor boosted its notoriety!

> 1891   Boston Daily Globe 6 Dec. 17 (advt.)    15 styles Skin and
>   Plush Horses.

and

> 1954   Austin (Minnesota) Daily Herald 9    They seem to eat just as
>   well and are dressed like Astor's plush horse.

I agree:  Socialite Mrs. Astor had a particularly lavish party in her 5th Ave mansion and in the front window she placed one of her (live) horses adorned with lights.

As for lit up:

**light up**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lit+up) an idiom

**To brighten or illuminate something.**

Comment: I've never read the story but I'm a Google expert it seems.  https://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/mrs-astor%27s-horse/first-edition/

Comment: Thank you, but I already know this. I am looking for "lit up" or a similar phrase. There is a difference.

Comment: "I agree: Socialite Mrs. Astor had a particularly lavish party in her 5th Ave mansion and in the front window she placed one of her (live) horses adorned with lights." Where did you get this from? I read a number of books about the Astors, Vanderbilts, Morgans, etc. a few year ago and I just can't remember